# Best CMS for a T-Shirt catalog website

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce

Hi my friend who's studying CSS wants to make a simple t-shirt catalog website. He also wants to include e-commerece in the future. What's an easy to learn CMS--preferrably in PHP--do you guys suggest for him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) as the main CMS because it's way easier to learn that [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/).

Drupal now also features plugins(modules) which can be used to create a store ([Shop Modules on Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/modules?text=shop)), bind it to other data sources like SVN and even get it to work

Personally I have set up tons of Joomla projects and it's always difficult to get the things done easy and fast.

Joomla really is too big if you plan to have a small site.

Answer (score 2):

I recently tried out [oxid](http://www.oxid-esales.com) eShop which I liked very much.

It's pretty basic, yet very flexible and extensible.

It's very easy to understand and comes with a nice AJAX interface.

Also it's design can be changed with an interface editor that doesn't require you to know anything about programming.

If you want to have a first look at it without installing it here's the link to the [store](http://demoshop.oxid-esales.com/community-edition/) and to its [admin area](http://demoshop.oxid-esales.com/community-edition/admin/index.php). The login for the admin area is admin/admin(user/pass).

It might not be as feature-complete/professional as for example [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) which is a full-fleged shop-system, but I'm pretty sure that's exactly what your friend needs.

It also has been featured in the july's issue [php|architect](http://www.phparch.com/magazine/index/101) .

Answer (score 1):

also check good old Zen Cart: http://www.zen-cart.com

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend [OXID e-Shop](http://www.oxid-esales.com).  We've been a doing a number of e-Commerce sites based on it and chose it over Magento, XT-Commerce etc al.

Best things I like about OXID are speed and features.  Templating is SMARTY based.  We got our first sites up and running in 1-2 hours, while Magento took a full day.

Good luck!

Ashant

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to build my own admin tools but lately I have been using [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) which is a PHP CMS. I have never done ecommerce with it myself, but I have seen a few sites that use Joomla and have nice ecommerce systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be prepared for the future please look at some ecommerce software. These are in general better than a CMS with ecommerce functionality.

For example look at:
[OsCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/)
[PHPCart](http://www.phpcart.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out CataBlog, it is a WordPress plugin that lets you easily upload images and create a catalog or store of t-shirts. It uses PayPal as the main revenue collection but you may also change the rendered html form for the buy now button to integrate it with any other shopping cart.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/catablog/

Answer (score 0):

[Magento](http://magento.com/) of course, that is one of the best for selling things.